# How to animate cursor immediately on click, while JavaScript is running, before Postback

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-visualization

I'm implementing Google Charts and providing the option to export them to PDF or Word.  In order to achieve this, I am calling the getImageURI() method after each chart is drawn.  These are on reports, and some reports have quite a few images.

On one that has nearly 100, Firefox is giving a warning message for a script that is taking too long.  If I remove the image creation part, it runs much faster.  However, I need to generate those at some point.

My first attempt was to run a new JavaScript method to do this when the Export to Word/Excel was clicked, prior to sending that command back to the server.  This works fine, **but I can't get the animation of the cursor in progress to begin right away.**

```
drawChartsWithImageGeneration: function () {

    $("body").addClass("cursorProgress"); // changes cursor

    $("div.chartContainer").each(function () {
        var chartContainer = $(this);
        drawChart(chartContainer);
    });

    $("body").removeClass("cursorProgress"); // changes cursor back
}
```

If I add a console.log() at the beginning of the function, it does execute immediately.  However, for some reason, the class is not added to the body tag until the drawChart() function completes and the PostBack ensues.

The Anchor tag that initiates this has the doPostBack on the href and the drawChartsWithImageGeneration on the onclick event.

(FYI: Using C#)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you could do is change your drawChart function to take in a callback which gets executed [after the chart is rendered](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/events?hl=en).  Loop through each one of the charts and render each with a millisecond gap between. This should give the cursor enough time to change on the screen.

Also, if there are hundreds of charts on the page, the millisecond gap between each chart render will keep browsers (Firefox) from complaining about an unresponsive script.

```js
drawChart: function (container, callback) {
    // Chart creation logic here
    // somewhere create an instance of the google chart object 
    // and call it "chart" for use below

    google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', callback || $.noop);
},

drawChartsWithImageGeneration: function () {
    var $chartContainers = $("div.chartContainer");
    var chartCount = $chartContainers.length;

    $("body").addClass("cursorProgress"); // changes cursor

    // Draw each chart one at a time, change the cursor back when all charts have finished
    (function doDraw(index) {
        if (index < chartCount) {
            setTimeout(function() {
                drawChart($chartContainers.eq(index), function () {
                    doDraw(index + 1);
                });
            }, 1);
        }
        else {
            $("body").removeClass("cursorProgress"); // changes cursor back

            // Whatever else you need to do after all charts are ready
        }
    })(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be that the DOM did not have enough time between functions to update.
Try setting a timeout for 300 ms before continuing the rest of your functions.

It could also be that your drawChart function is not waited on to be completed to start the script that removes the cursorProgress class.
Try moving the remove cursorProgress class function to the end of your drawChart function.